# Javascript fetch API doesnt work when used in EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch a file called files.json from the root directory of the (locally hosted) NodeJS backend and then print it out in the console.

```
<script>
fetch("./files.json")
    .then(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(obj => {
        console.log(obj);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
</script>
```

Using this code in the index.ejs file delivers the following error in the browser's console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/files.json [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

However, when I use the exact same code in an .html file that's hosted locally with Visual Studio Code's LiveServer plugin, I get the desired result:

```
Object { files: (3) […] }
```

If it's relevant, files.json has the following content:

```
{
"files": [
    {
        "name": "testfile1"
    },
    {
        "name": "testfile2"
    },
    {
        "name": "testfile3"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your data output into string i.e.,

```js
 var yourDataStr = JSON.stringify(yourdata)
```

and then validate your data with:

```js
JSON.parse(yourDataStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think that `fetch()` won't work with NodeJS. It is only native feature in browsers (Client-side Javascript) So it won't work in NodeJS. To solve this you must download Library in NodeJS that will support `fetch()` in NodeJS like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

1. Install `node-fetch` using `npm install node-fetch`.
2. Then try this example :

```js
fetch('') // Here add location for JSON file
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json));
```